# Visual Studio Standalone Profiling

Tags: visualstudio

I'm trying to automate the profiling of a Visual Studio Native C++ Project (2015 and / or 2019). To do so I'm using the standalone profiling tools of Visual Studio VSPerf (and related) and VSDiagnostics. My Question is how to get the total memory consumption of an executable with on of these standalone tools? I know how it's done in the UI but not with commandline parameter.

I already searched other agents for VSDiagnostics.

I tried the approach of [Egor4eg](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3839425/8684589) as well as

```
$ vsdiagnostics start 0 /loadConfig:<AgentConfigFromDir> /launch:executable.exe
<...>
$ vsdiagnostics  stop 0 /output:output.diagsession
```